# Apply String modification to Array/List

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

Given an `ArrayList<String>` of filenames with file extension, how can I idiomatically get that same array with all the filenames sans file extension.

There's a lot of ways to do this and I could easily just create a new array but I'm wondering if there's a nice clean way to do this with a one-liner.

For now I am doing like so:

```
List<String> namesWithExt = ...
List<String> namesWithoutExt = new ArrayList<>();
namesWithExt.forEach(name -> namesWithoutExt.add(FilenameUtils.removeExtension(name)));
String[] namesWithoutExt = namesWithExt.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Stream`s:

```
String[] namesWithoutExt = 
    namesWithExt.stream()
                .map(name -> FilenameUtils.removeExtension(name))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

or:

```
String[] namesWithoutExt = 
    namesWithExt.stream()
                .map(FilenameUtils::removeExtension)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Or using a method reference: `.map(FilenameUtils::removeExtension)`

Comment: This is what I'm looking for - thanks. I'm gonna wait a day before I accept your answer to see if anyone else has something to add as well.